# Share raspberry pi ethernet connection via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, ethernet

So, basically I'm moving into a new flat for university and the only possibility to get internet access currently is through ethernet ports.

I know you can do bluetooth tethering to get your smartphones internet onto the raspberry pi as has been asked here before. But can I do the reverse? Like, configure my raspberry to share its internet access (ethernet) over bluetooth to my phone?

My basic problem is that I'm redditing (a lot) late at night and in the morning in bed and this would literally use up all my mobile data. Without a WiFi (and being forbidden to setup an access point) this will cause problems sooner or later if I don't want to change my habits.

If there's some other easier idea that I'm not thinking of right now I'm also open for that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have android phone it seems you can connect ethernet cable: https://youtu.be/uisnj8Xufp0

Comment: It makes much more sense to share the internet via wifi, unless for some reason the wifi on the phone or the pi is being used for something else (which sounds unlikely since you've said the only available internet in the room is via ethernet).